# Add more border padding around the review queues dropdown in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, design, top-bar

I have suggestion regarding better readability by adding more spacing around element. When you click **Review queues** (which is placed 3rd in row) in navigation menu and when there are no reviews available, it says "There are no review queues available to you". I feel if we have more spacing around copy, would be better readable.

[image: There are no review queues]

**My suggestion**: To add more spacing around element for better readability. It doesn't necessary have to be same as what I've suggested. It's my suggestion/thoughts.

[image: Better Readability]

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. Recent changes to the dropdown menus on Stack Overflow (presumably as they update everything to use their new “Stacks” design language) have reduced the amount of border padding, which reduces readability and aesthetic appeal. This should be fixed as the dropdown is updated to indicate *why* there are no review queues available to you: because you are banned from reviewing!

Answer (score 5):

Just merged a fix for this. It'll go out in the next build, whenever that is, heh. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Is this a one-off fix for the review queue drop-down in particular, or does it add padding to all the dropdowns from the top bar (e.g., inbox, achievements, navigation if the fixed left sidebar is turned off, etc.)?

Comment: @CodyGray I can see overall 8px of padding around and it looks fixed to me. I think, someone need to update to status completed. Thanks for fixing it.